# mongoDB finding a customer by state and displaying its ID

Tags: database, mongodb

So i have a data base schema that goes as such:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5a310e7c202c89656807819e"),
"customerId" : "A1284",
"name" : "CA Technologies",
"firstOrder" : 2012,
"tenure" : 5,
"sales" : [
    {
        "year" : 2014,
        "amount" : 130269
    },
    {
        "year" : 2015,
        "amount" : 139387.83
    },
    {
        "year" : 2016,
        "amount" : 156114.3696
    },
    {
        "year" : 2017,
        "amount" : 170164.6629
    }
],
"averageSales" : 148983.96562499998,
"rebate" : 59593.58624999999,
"discount" : 8508.233145,
"state" : "FL",
"membershipCode" : 4,
"totalSales" : 595935.8624999999
```

}
how do i pull information from the data like this one:
What customer has the highest totalSales in NY.  Answer with customerId

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just order your items by *totalSales* in desceding order and take first result.

```
db.customers.find({state: "NY"}, {customerId: 1}).sort({totalSales: -1}).limit(1)
```

To limit the number of returned fields you can use projection and specify only customerId.